# Significant performance difference for downloading images with HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0 using Firefox and Chromium?

Tags: http

When hosting a web page with many small images (around 500 images with size <100x100 in pixels) within the static directory using Python Flask on local device and view it with Firefox 74 and Chrome 80 respectively, a significant performance difference is noted:

- With HTTP/1.0, the loading time is: Firefox 3.12s, Chrome 30s.
- With HTTP/1.1, the loading time is: Firefox 3.68s, Chrome 1.7s.

It seems that Chromium is fast with HTTP/1.1 but extremely slow when using HTTP/1.0. I'd like to known why there's such difference?

---

App demo:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler
#WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000)
```

- Install Python 3.5+.
- Install Flask: `pip install flask`.
- Save the above script as `app.py`.
- Create an HTML page `index.html` with about 500 images in the `static` directory which is in the same directory as `app.py`.
- Run `app.py` to start the local server.
- Access `localhost:8000/static/index.html` in the browser.
- Remove `#` from the commented line to host HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/1.0.

Answer (score 1):

There were many performance improvements regarding persistent connections in HTTP/1.1:

- **Persistence by default** ([RFC 7230, 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3)) (multiple requests & responses over a single connection)
- **Chunked Transfer Coding** ([RFC 2616, 3.6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.6.1), updated by [RFC 7230, 3.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.1)) "allows dynamically produced content to be transferred along with the information necessary for the recipient to verify that it has received the full message."
- **Pipelining** ([RFC 7230, 6.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.2)) "(i.e., send multiple requests without waiting for each
  response)"
- **Range Requests** ([RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)), although they don't apply to your use case.

Therefore, getting better performance with HTTP/1.0 and Firefox 74 is most likely a measurement error, whereas the results with Google Chrome 80 seems reasonable. I'd guess the images were already cached in Firefox.

However, this day and age you shouldn't be worrying about HTTP/1.0, an ancient protocol from 1996. According to W3Techs [usage statistics](https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/ce-http2), as of March 2020, 44 % of all websites have already moved to **HTTP/2** ([RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)), providing more performance improvements:

- **Binary data format** reduces the amount of data transferred.
- **Header Compression** ([section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-4.3)) and **Reuse**.
- **Persistent TCP connections** i.e. multiple simultaneus downloads over a single connection.
- **Streams and Multiplexing** ([section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5)).
- **Server push** ([section 8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.2)) allows the server to push resources the client hasn't yet requested.

These would probably give *significantly* better performance in your use case. Also, **HTTP/3** (with QUIC) is coming; it's already supported in both Firefox (from 72.0.1)  and Chrome (from 79). Forget HTTP/1.0 – it's time to move on.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Caching is probably not the cause as I run every test using forced refresh (Ctrl+F5) and run for multiple times and have always get similar result that Firefox won't load more than 10 secs. I agree that 3.12s and 3.68s for Firefox can be somehow a measurement error, but 3s and 30s is so big a significant difference that cannot be explained by caching. After all, my original question that why Chrome is so slow for HTTP/1.0 is still await for explanation.

Comment: Could you give link to the HTTP/1.0 page in question? Reproducing this from scratch would require too much work considering the low general usefulness of the results.

Comment: I don't have an open HTTP/1.0 server for illustration. As OP says, it can be created with Python Flask 1.* (which, by documentation, supports multi-threading reuest handling by default) local server hosting a page with many small to medium images in a static directory.

Comment: The Network tab on the Developer Tools should show you the waterfall, explaining the order og the requests and the duration of different phases. From there you can figure out what it's waiting for, which might answer your question.

Comment: Added a demo app in the original question.

Comment: It seems that the `queue` and `stale` peroid are significant larger for HTTP/1.0 than HTTP/1.1 in Chrome. Chrome allows at most 6 connections to each originat the same time, and it seems that HTTP/1.1 greatly reduce the time to initialize connection by persistent connection. However, Firefox seems to also has a limit of 6 connections per origin, but why doesn't Firefox have such long queue and stale time in HTTP/1.0?